# NoClassDefFoundError: in jenkins-test-harness-htmlunit library

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins-plugins

I am developing test cases for one of my plugin.  Below is snipped code of test case:

JenkinsRule.WebClient webClient=rule.createWebClient();
       FreeStyleProject p = (FreeStyleProject) rule.jenkins.getItem("WebApp");

```
  HtmlPage page=  webClient.getPage(p,"configure");
```

.
I am always getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.EncodingSniffer . I have checked dependency jenkins-test-harness-htmlunit and it has same class.

I am having below jenkins and jenkins-test-harness version in my plugin:

```
<properties>
    <jenkins.version>2.7.3</jenkins.version>
    <java.level>8</java.level>

<jenkins-test-harness.version>2.27</jenkins-test-harness.version>
</properties>
```

Please help me if anybody has solution for it